# UIActionsheet in Ios8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, uiactionsheet, uiactionsheetdelegate

I have implemented actionsheet in my project having deploy target ios7 and less actionsheet works fine.

UIActionsheet in Ios8 not working same as other version of Ios.
How i make it working properly?

Thanks

Comment: You should give example of what and how is not working right.

Answer (score 5):

UIActionSheet is deprecated from iOS8, You should use UIAlertController. You have to choose the alert style: it could be an AlertView or a Sheet. Check [here](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIAlertController) for Apple reference. See [this](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/09/05/uialertcontroller-changes-in-ios-8.html) for an example.

Comment: This is a bogus answer! Yes, UIActionSheet is deprecated in iOS8, meaning its use is not encouraged and may be removed in future iOS. *However* it works fine in iOS8 - while there are some changes that make it work differently - to wit, `[actSheet showInView:self.view.window]` doesn't seem to work - but note that was sending UIWindow w/o controller. So the question is right, albeit incomplete - and this answer is wrong